# How do I dynamically call a Web Service using just JAX-WS?

Tags: java, jax-ws

I'm building an application and I want a user to be able set a WSDL in the configuration and for my application to use that as it is running, i.e. I don't know what it is at compilation time.

The WSDL will have a single schema and I only want to call one service in it (to return a response from an earlier request made to my application).

I want to dynamically call the single service using Java. I want to do this without making use of wsimport, Apache CXF or Axis 2.0.

How can I do this just using JAX-WS ?

Comment: What are you hoping to save by not generating stubs and beans from the WSDL? The answer you give will affect the approach.

Comment: Woops, then I missed the mark with my answer. Sorry.

Comment: Will there be different schemas at those different WSDL locations? If so I'm not sure how you would handle that without using a DOM-based library like SAAJ. Otherwise, it should be possible to use JAX-WS with different WSDL locations as long as the WSDL files are the same.